# Socket.io getting total clicks from all users

Tags: javascript, socket.io

So currently I'm trying to achieve that is when user clicks button it adds +1 to counter and then when another user connects it goes counting not from 0 but from 1.

But what is happening now is when I joined with first user, I clicked 10 times, and then I join with another user and click the button it again starts from 0 and not from 10. In other words the counter is counting seperate users clicks but not total of all users.

This is my server.js:

```
var user = 0;
var totalClicksFromOneUser = 0;
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('buttonClicked', (data) => {
        totalClicksFromOneUser = data.totalClicks;
        io.emit('clicksCountFromUsers', {
            clicks: totalClicksFromOneUser
        });
    });

    io.emit('totalClickedTimes', {
        clicks: totalClicksFromOneUser
    });

    io.emit('totalUsers', {
        usersCount: user = user + 1
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        io.emit('userdc', {
            usersCount: user = user - 1
        });
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="usersCount"></h1>
    <button id="clicker">CLICK ME</button>
    <p id="totalClicks"></p>

    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        var socket = io();
        var clicks = 0;

        socket.on('connect', function(data){
            console.log("You're connected");
        });

        socket.on('totalUsers', function(data){
            $('#usersCount').text(data.usersCount);
        });

        socket.on('userdc', function(data){
            $('#usersCount').text(data.usersCount);
        });

        $('#clicker').on('click', function(){
            socket.emit('buttonClicked', {
                totalClicks: clicks = clicks + 1
            });
        });

        socket.on('clicksCountFromUsers', function(data){
            $('#totalClicks').text(data.clicks);
        });

        socket.on('totalClickedTimes', function(data){
            $('#totalClicks').text(data.clicks);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log("User disconnected");
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re only setting text on screen to the initial value here

```
socket.on('clicksCountFromUsers', function(data){
    $('#totalClicks').text(data.clicks);
});
```

You’re not initializing `clicks` variable in any way so it’ll stay zero. Change it to

```
socket.on('clicksCountFromUsers', function(data){
    $('#totalClicks').text(data.clicks);
    clicks = data.clicks;
});
```

and it’ll save the received state.

This code might still reset to any state the last clicker does since you’re sending the end value to the server and storing it rather than calculating and keeping the value at server.